# start shell script at boot time in linux redhat

Tags: linux, redirect

I want to run one shell script during booting of my linux server having redhat.

Below are the steps I followed to achieve this

1) I have created script /home/user/script/test.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "xyz" >> output
```

2) I have made script file as executable using below command

```
chmod +x /home/user/script/test.sh
```

3) I have created put `test.sh` file inside `/etc/init.d` directory

4) I have made soft link for using below command

```
 ls -s /etc/init.d/test.sh /etc/rc.d/S15test.sh
```

5) reboot the server

Another things I have tried is put below line inside `/etc/rc.local` file

```
/bin/sh /home/user/script/test.sh
```

But still I am not able to execute code written inside `test.sh` file.

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20357/how-can-i-make-a-script-in-etc-init-d-start-at-boot

Comment: It probably runs somewhere else than you expect. Look for `/output` or change the script to write to an absolute path name (probably the better alternative).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the RedHat documentation [RUNNING ADDITIONAL PROGRAMS AT BOOT TIME](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-boot-init-shutdown-run-boot.html), you can add commands to the `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` script.

If you are not seeing anything, try turning on tracing in the rc.local script to see what is happening:

```
set -x
```

and you can send the trace to a known log file if you want:

```
exec 2>/tmp/logfile
```

Comment: /etc/rc.local is the soft link of /etc/rc.d/rc.local